# How to "Draw Over Other Apps" in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic4

Is there a way to draw over other apps in Ionic 4? I'm building a streaming app and would love to use functionality similar to the google maps app for Android. When "minimized", it draws a smaller window map over other apps.

How can I achieve something similar with Ionic 4?

I have found an old Cordova plugin, so it seems the functionality could be possible, but it seems not to be compatible with ionic 4, but I might be wrong: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/draw-over-all-apps-cordova-plugin-for-android/92613

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-drawoverapps
 or 
cordova plugin add https://github.com/ahmedwahba/cordova-plugin-drawoverapps

```
 window.overApps.checkPermission(function(msg){
         console.log(msg);
  });
```